# Configuration error: You must configure at least one set of arguments for this @ParameterizedTest

Tags: java, gradle, junit, parameters, interface

I am trying to run tests of a interface and read that i should use @ParameterizedTest. The error is shown below.

Here's my code:

```
package de.rhenus.fl.dpx.commons.mapstruct.date;

import de.rhenus.fl.dpx.commons.business.micronaut.date.EmbeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

class EmbeddedOffsetDateTimeOracleMapperTest {
    final EmbeddedOffsetDateTimeOracleMapper mapper;
    final OffsetDateTime NOW = OffsetDateTime.now();


    public EmbeddedOffsetDateTimeOracleMapperTest(EmbeddedOffsetDateTimeOracleMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    void embeddedOffsetDateTimeOracleToOffsetDateTime() {
        EmbeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle embeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle = new EmbeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle();
        embeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle.setOffset(0);
        embeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle.setValue(NOW.toLocalDateTime());

        OffsetDateTime result = mapper.map(embeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle);
        assertThat("Same OffsetDateTime", result.equals(NOW));

    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    void offsetDateTimeToEmbeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle() {
        EmbeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle embeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle = new EmbeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle();
        embeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle.setOffset(0);
        embeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle.setValue(NOW.toLocalDateTime());

        OffsetDateTime result = mapper.map(embeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle);
        assertThat("Same OffsetDateTime", result.equals(NOW));

    }
}
```

Here's my error:

> Configuration error: You must configure at least one set of arguments for this @ParameterizedTest
> org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Configuration error: You must configure at least one set of arguments for this @ParameterizedTest
> at org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions.condition(Preconditions.java:281)

Where do I need to pass parameters to run my test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Junit5, for each parameterized test, you would need to pass a value set. You can refer to the documentation for the same: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests .

In your case, it should be something as follow:

```java
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(ints = { -3, 0, 1, 2, 3 })
    void offsetDateTimeToEmbeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle(int offset) {
        EmbeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle embeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle = new EmbeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle();
        embeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle.setOffset(offset);
        embeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle.setValue(NOW.toLocalDateTime());

        OffsetDateTime result = mapper.map(embeddedOffsetDateTimeOracle);
        assertThat("Same OffsetDateTime", result.equals(NOW + offset));

    }
```